# MSF for Agile v5.0 has No "Resolved" State

Tags: tfs

We have recently started to use TFS and are using the MSF for Agile v5.0 Template.  Tasks that I have created seem to only have 2 states.  Active and Closed.  In reading the documentation that I have found ... it shows that there should also be a "Resolved" state so that when developers are finished they can mark it Resolved and then once the task is tested it can be marked Closed.

Can somebody help me understand what I'm missing?  Is there a step I'm missing in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assaf Stone's answer is an accurate solution for part of the question I asked, but I understand now that I really was "Missing" something.

After spending time with TFS, I figured out why they removed the "Resolved" state from Task.  A task should be linked to a user story and As a user story is where the testing or next step would be.  A task does not need a "Resolved" state.

Now if you wanted to add an additional step for a task such as "Code Review" that would be valid but there is not a need for "Resolved" on the Task itself.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't use the right Process Template, only **MSF Agile for CMMI Improvement** has the resolved state, MSF Agile Software Development only has Active and Closed in the version 5.0.

You did have the Resolved state in the version 4.0 though.

Answer (score 1):

It's true, but you can easily copy the workflow from the user story WIT definition. just export the two with witadmin, and copy the workflow from the user story to the task.

Comment: Do you have a blog or entry that explains this?  I'll look and see what I find but I'm new the TFS admin role.  What is a WIT?

Comment: Look at http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=753 for instructions on how to export and import WIT definitions from the CMD line. In http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=755 (part two of previous post), there's an explanation how to use the power tools. Also in part two is an example of editing the WITd's workflow - which is what you need. Finally, the MSDN documentation is surprisingly understandable. Read it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms243849(v=vs.100).aspx. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at the donnetcurry article, I had already found the msdn documentation and have exported the xml.  Do you know if these changes apply to all projects using the template or can they be applied just to a single project?

Comment: You're welcome. If you like, you can rank, or even mark as the answer :)

Comment: Assaf, can you confirm that if I do the Witadmin import that it will only impact the project listed and not change the "default" project template?  I don't see any mention of that in any of the articles.

Comment: Yes. Both the **power-tools**-based command (Tools > Process Editor > Work Item Types > Import WIT), and the command (witadmin importwitd) will import the work item only into the **selected team project**. Importing into the process template requires a completely different set of actions.